# Files missing after Ubuntu 10.10 server reboot

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

I am running a 10.10 server running samba. I shut down the server to install a hard drive for backups. After I rebooted, I remounted the drives and restarted the shares. Now about 10 very important files are missing. The rest of the share works perfectly fine. Any ideas or help would be a life saver.

Comment: After a bit of digging i found two of the files but the are hidden and have .~lock before the file name? What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you looking for the missing files?  Are you using graphical windows like Windows explorer, or are you at the ubuntu command line?  You should be at the command line if you want a good search.  A couple of options are the find command, and the locate command.

Something like this:

```
cd /
find . -name '*myfilename*' -print
```

Will search / and everything under it.  Or cd into the folder where the files should be first.

```
locate myfilename
```

Is worth a shot, too.  But, you may need to do an updatedb first as root, though, which could take a while.